# Joining two collections on multiple columns in AWS Document DB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aws-documentdb, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

I am new to AWS DocumentDB and trying to execute a simple query that would find entries from two collections where 3 fields are the same.

SQL version:

Select * from A a join B b on A.id = B.id where a.ax = b.bx and a.ay = b.by and a.az = b.bz

I found that mongo db can get it using the following command that uses pipeline:

{
"$lookup": {
"from": "A",
"pipeline": [
{
"$match": {
"$expr": {
"$eq": [
"$ax",
"$bx"
]
}
}
}
],
"as": "result"
}

However, the same query is not supported in document Db. While trying to run a similar command on MongoDB Compass (over document db cluster), I get a feature not supported error and an Uncorrelated query not supported error.

Am I doing something wrong here. What is the correct way of joing 2 collections on multiple column in AWS document db.

Comment: AWS documentDB supports MongoDB 4.0, the syntax you are trying to use, I think, came after 4.0.

Comment: What would be the way to fetch this data in AWS DDB then? Any ideas ?

Comment: Depends on what are you trying to achieve. But looking at your SQL query, I think you are using lookup, in the wrong way. Ideally where clause in mysql, is $match in mongo